# SQL query to select dates between two dates and exclude dates between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#temp1]
(
    [workDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Id] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#temp1] 
VALUES ('12-01-2018', '11'), ('11-01-2018', '11'),
       ('10-01-2018', '11'), ('09-01-2018', '11')


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#temp2]
(
    [workDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Id] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[#temp2] 
VALUES ('10-01-2018', '11'), ('09-01-2018', '11')
```

I have 2 tables with dates.

I want to select all the dates from `#temp1` but do not count the dates from `#temp2`.

I used, but did not get the desired result:

```
select A.workDate, A.Id
from [dbo].[#temp1] A
left join [dbo].[#temp2] B on A.Id = B.Id and A.workDate = B.workDate
where A.workDate between CAST('09.01.2018' as datetime) and CAST('12.01.2018' as datetime)
   or B.workDate not between CAST('09.01.2018' as datetime) and CAST('10.01.2018' as datetime)
```

The result I want to get:

```
workDate                   Id
-------------------------------
2018-01-12 00:00:00.000    11
2018-01-11 00:00:00.000    11
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select rows having dates between two date values and which are not in an other table, first select the rows using `Between .. and` in a `Where` clause and omit the dates which are part of other table using **`Not Exists`**.

**Query**

```
select * from [dbo].[#temp1] as [t1]
where cast([workDate] as date) between '2018-09-01' and '2018-12-01'
and not exists(
    select 1 from [dbo].[#temp2] as [t2]
    where [t1].[workDate] = [t2].[workDate]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the query depends on the values in the tables.  If you already know the dates you want to select, you can just do this:

```
where A.workDate between CAST('11.01.2018' as datetime) and CAST('12.01.2018' as datetime)
```

What you probably want instead is this, to select rows where the `left join` does not match anything:

```
where B.workDate is null
```

Answer (score 0):

`A.Id=B.Id` - this condition in join predicate is logically wrong/makes no sense. You were talking about comparing dates - what would `Id`s be here for? Same thing about `OR` part in `where`.

As you stated your job: dates from #temp1 except dates from #temp2 - it can be "translated" from english into SQL almost word to word:

```
select A.workDate
from [dbo].[#temp1] A
where A.workDate between CAST('09.01.2018' as datetime) and CAST('12.01.2018' as datetime)

EXCEPT

select B.workData
from [dbo].[#temp2] B
```

or *"dates from #temp1 which do not exist in #temp2"*:

```
select A.workDate,A.Id
from [dbo].[#temp1] A
where A.workDate between CAST('09.01.2018' as datetime) and CAST('12.01.2018' as datetime)
  AND not exists(select 1 from [dbo].[#temp2] B WHERE B.workDate = A.workDate)
```

Yes, that simple.

Also you better don't cast dates like that: `CAST('09.01.2018' as datetime)`. "Default" date [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) depends on settings and can be, e.g.

- `ddmmyy` German
- `yymmdd` ANSI
- `mmddyy` USA

So this cast may result different dates (month 09 day 01 or month 01 day 09?)
Use `CONVERT(datetime, '09.01.2018', 104)`. And better tend not to use literals and magic strings/numbers within a query - put those values into variables and use them like that:

```
declare @date_begin date = CONVERT(date, '20180109', 112),
        @date_end date = CONVERT(date, '20180112', 112)

select A.workDate,A.Id
from [dbo].[#temp1] A
where A.workDate between @date_begin and @date_end
  AND not exists(select 1 from [dbo].[#temp2] B WHERE B.workDate = A.workDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your query with `and` condition as below. And check that `B.workDate IS NULL` so that is record doesn't exist in `[dbo].[#temp2]` then also it will give the result.

```
select A.workDate, A.Id
from [dbo].[#temp1] A
left join [dbo].[#temp2] B on A.Id = B.Id and A.workDate = B.workDate
where A.workDate between CAST('09.01.2018' as datetime) and CAST('12.01.2018' as datetime)
and (B.workDate IS NULL or B.workDate not between CAST('09.01.2018' as datetime) and CAST('10.01.2018' as datetime)
```